# rephrase definition for android orientation angle "roll"

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, sensormanager

The definition of 'roll' in android is:

> angle between a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane perpendicular to the ground

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#getOrientation(float%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D)).

Maybe I'm missing something, but there seem to be many planes perpendicular to the ground giving many different angles.

Could someone please rephrase this definition using e.g planes parallel to ground or screen, north direction, gravity direction?

NB! I am asking for a rephrasing using different words. I know the official definition as I have stated. Please don't repost the official definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the mentioned docs:

> Roll, angle of rotation about the y axis. This value represents the
> angle between a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane
> perpendicular to the ground.

From another [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position):

> Roll (degrees of rotation about the y axis). This is the angle between
> a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane perpendicular
> to the ground. If you hold the device parallel to the ground with the
> bottom edge closest to you and tilt the left edge of the device toward
> the ground, the roll angle becomes positive. Tilting in the opposite
> direction—moving the right edge of the device toward the ground—
> causes the roll angle to become negative. The range of values is -90
> degrees to 90 degrees.

You may also have a look at that [picture](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381649/whats-the-best-3d-angular-co-ordinate-system-for-working-with-smartphone-apps)

The important point is **about the y-axis**. The y-axis is the one that goes positive from the bottom edge to the upper edge of the screen.

----EDIT----

A may be much more explicit picture [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/40876/versions/8/previews/sensorgroup/Examples/html/CapturingAzimuthRollPitchExample.html).

Comment: It seems you understand what this angle means, but still I asked for a rephrasing. The other doc says the same thing. As I mentioned in the question I am aware of this definition, but I don't undersand what it means by "plane perpendicular to other plane". There are many such planes.

Comment: @JoonatanTalviste look at the picture you will see what y-axis is. Then if screen plane and ground are parallel, angle is 0. If you read carefully you will understand. pitch, azimuth and roll are always defined the same (places, smartphones, etc). Search for "pitch azimuth roll" images on any search engine... It is very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

> values[2]: **Roll, angle of rotation about the y axis.** This value represents the angle between a plane perpendicular to the device's screen and a plane perpendicular to the ground. Assuming that the bottom edge of the device faces the user and that the screen is face-up, tilting the left edge of the device toward the ground creates a positive roll angle. The range of values is -π/2 to π/2.

The plane "perpendicular to the ground" here is just a reference for how "tilted" (rolled) the device is. Imagine the device flat on a table next to a wall. If you lift the edge of the device so it is tilted to the side, the angle of roll is the angle between the plane of the device and the plane of the wall. This is because we have constrained the x axis (pitch) so that you are looking at roll. Now, if you lift the top of the device towards you, the roll stays the same while the pitch changes, because the device is still at the same angle towards the wall along it's y axis.